# Объясните в чем разница в классах

Tags: swift

Изучаю онлайн курсы и столкнулся с таким вопросом -  в чем разница между NSData, NSDate and Data, Date? И тут же по теме - не изменилось ли приведение старых версий Swifta, в отличие от новых?

Comment: [Говорят](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39811352/2881286) суть одна и та же, без префикса введены в новой версии

Comment: хорошо, а между ними data и date в чем разница?

Comment: [`date`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date) - это дата. [`data`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data) - это бинарные данные

Comment: Разница в том, что это совершенно разные понятия.  Date это дата (день/месяц/год), а data это данные.

Answer (score 1):

Раньше, до появления **Swift** и в первых его версиях использовались подобные классы с префиксом **NS**, потому что они пришли из библиотек *NeXTSTEP*.

Собственно, с появлением **Swift** им на смену пришли аналогичные, которые более адаптированы под работу с этим языком.